# SOQL QueryResult returns Account name with prefix 'Account' in InnerText

Tags: soql, api, partner-wsdl

I'm using the Partner WSDL to query contacts via .Net.

I have simple SOQL query that pulls back every Contact with their email and Account Name:

```
SELECT Email, Account.Name FROM Contact
```

However when I inspect the sObject records that this returns, the Account Name field InnerText value is always prefixed with 'Account' e.g. 'AccountGrand Hotels & Resorts Ltd'.

Am I expected to strip off the 'Account' prefix or am I doing something incorrect. Below is an extract of the .Net code which queries the Contacts.

```
Dim soqlQuery As String = "SELECT Email, Account.Name FROM Contact"

Dim queryResult As QueryResult = Nothing

queryResult = helperBase.SoapClient.query(soqlQuery)

' when inspecting the below records 'Account' is prefixed to InnerText value
Dim records As Array = queryResult.records
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to type cast the result of helperBase.SoapClient.query(soqlQuery) like

List lstContacts = (List)helperBase.SoapClient.query(soqlQuery)

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Prakash, I don't understand. The type 'QueryResult' is fine here, I am able to loop through queryResult.records and get the sObjects that I need. How would type casting the Query Result help here?